# When is a Session created?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

On my login web page (i.e. the first page the user hits) I have code of this form:

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page {
  private MyClass _obj = new MyClass();
  ...
```

`MyClass` has the constructor:

```
public MyClass() {
  var sess = HttpContext.Current.Session; // no problem here
  sess["MyValue"] = 123; // throws null ref exception coz sess is null
}
```

As I've commented, the call to `sess["MyValue"]` throws a null reference exception, because the HttpContext hasn't yet created the session object.

So when is it safe to start accessing the Session object?  I don't want to give up on the inline declaration/initialization of `_obj`; that's very convenient for me!  What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to access the Session in or after the Page's [`OnInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.oninit.aspx) event, or `PreInit` if you're that bothered. Before that, and you're dicing with death.

Comment: I have a doubt , Lets say, I just created a  `AboutUs` page in asp.net Mvc application which just returns a `View` , Will this create a new session for the request for the user or does Session is created using the code in our application like form authentication ?

Comment: @stom I don't quite understand your question. My answer relates to WebForms (MVC is a bit different, and depends on whether you use MVC or MVC Core). Any chance you could put together a different question with code examples?

Comment: Also, if you look at another, fuller, answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42621753/26479), you can see how this relates to ASP.NET applications that use Http Modules

Answer (score 4):

The session is created in *aquireRequestState* event of Http Module pipeline. I have tried to explain this whole thing below in detail.

We have below events in Http Module pipeline:
**(Pre - Page Life Cycle)**
1. BeginRequest
2. AuthenticateRequest
3. AuthorizeRequest
4. ResolveRequestCache
5. *AcquireRequestState*
6. PreRequestHandlerExecute

**Post - Page life cycle**
7. PostRequestHandlerExecute
8. ReleaseRequestState
9. UpdateRequestCache
10. EndRequest

Now, as we are aware, the first event in page life cycle is *PreInit*.
You are trying to create the object *_obj* before *PreInit* event. In the request life cycle, this process of creation of object and execution of constructor is done during ResolveRequestCache i.e; before *AcquireRequestState* event (since this is directly created in class and not any method). As expected, the session will still not be available in the constructor as *AcquireRequestState* is not yet executed.

*PreInit* method in page life cycle is called after *AcquireRequestState* and hence the session is available there.

**Conclusion:**
Earliest session operations can be done anytime after *AcquireRequestState* in Http Modules (if you are intercepting the request programmatically) or in/after *PreInit* method.

Answer (score 2):

If the user is on the first page of the site, then the Session has no objects in it.  You should definitely check the value before assigning to it.

```
if (Session["MyValue"] == null)
   Session.Add("MyValue", "");

Session["MyValue"] = "123";
```

You can also add the Global.asax file to the project.  That is where you can handle the `Session_Start` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the http pipeline. Rich Starhl has a [nice article.](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp) . Your session objects are created/retrieved during aquireRequestState event. If you have HTTP Modules which intercept the request before this event, your session might not have been initialized